# Problems with ANT installation

Tags: java, android, ant

Please excuse my french english ^^

I have got a probleme with the ANT installation...

- I've download the ANT Zip on the apache website
- I've set the environment variable ANT_HOME to : C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.4
- I've set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
- I've add, in the PATH variable : C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin

But when I want to test the "ant" or "ant -version" command in the CMD, I've have got this error : (in french for me :P, I have translate for you :D)
“ant” is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Have you got an idea ?

I have to install this program to use "zxing" on Android :)

Thanks !

Comment: If you CD to the ant bin directory and run ant there does it produce the same error?

Comment: have you extrated the ZIP contents on the folder you mentioned (C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.4)? then, there is a binary called ant.exe on this folder? is your JDK in the folder that JAVA_HOME points (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07)? maybe you have a French Windows distribution that has different folder names.

Comment: Logoff : In french Windows distributions, path are the same as you. Those path are corrects... John : If I CD in the bin directory, I've got those errors : Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar AND Buildfile: build.xml doesn't exists ! Build failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in the PATH environment variable are not applied on opened command line.

If you just changed the PATH, you need to open a new command line terminal. You can check by typing `echo %PATH%`.